# How to use Font Awesome in QML

Tags: qt, qml, font-awesome

Does anyone knows how to use Font Awesome in QML? I couldn't find any document or any information how to use Font Awesome in QML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I like to do is use [fontello](http://fontello.com/) to create a minimal set of icons, rather than downloading the whole set from FontAwesome. Using the [texteditor](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/examples/quickcontrols2/texteditor) example as a reference:

1. Download the font and store it somewhere in your project directory. In the example, it's in the `fonts` folder.
2. If you're using .qrc files in your project, add it to [one of those](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/examples/quickcontrols2/texteditor/texteditor.qrc).
3. There are two ways that I can think of to have the font recognised in your QML: [`FontLoader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html) and [`QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont). To use `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont()`, add [this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/examples/quickcontrols2/texteditor/texteditor.cpp#n77) code before loading your application's QML:

   ```
   QFontDatabase fontDatabase;
   if (fontDatabase.addApplicationFont(":/fonts/fontello.ttf") == -1)
       qWarning() << "Failed to load fontello.ttf";
   ```
4. Use the [Unicode codes](http://fontawesome.io/icon/folder-open-o/) in the `text` property of [whatever item](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/examples/quickcontrols2/texteditor/qml/texteditor.qml#n217) you want to display the icon in:

   ```
   ToolButton {
       id: openButton
       text: "\uF115" // icon-folder-open-empty
       font.family: "fontello"
       onClicked: openDialog.open()
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Mitch, you save my day.

Comment: Since `FontLoader` just uses `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont()` under the hood, can't you use it in the same way with the `font.family` as a string without using the `FontLoader` `id`?

Comment: Perhaps, I didn't bother to check that far, was just going off the documentation, which uses it with an `id`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution here : 
https://martin.rpdev.net/2018/03/30/using-fontawesome-5-in-qml.html

I personnaly mixed it with [this solution for FontAwesome 4.7](https://github.com/QMLCommunity/font-awesome-qml) which gives me this :

```
Item {
    id: awesome

    property alias icons: variables

    readonly property FontLoader fontAwesomeRegular: FontLoader {
        source: "./fa-regular-400.ttf"
    }
    readonly property FontLoader fontAwesomeSolid: FontLoader {
        source: "./fa-solid-900.ttf"
    }
    readonly property FontLoader fontAwesomeBrands: FontLoader {
        source: "./fa-brands-400.ttf"
    }

    readonly property string regular: fontAwesomeRegular.name
    readonly property string solid: fontAwesomeSolid.name
    readonly property string brands: fontAwesomeBrands.name

    Awesome.Variables {
        id: variables
    }
}
```

And `Awesome.Variables` is another file where I linked the icon names with their character code. Here is an excerpt :

```
QtObject {
    readonly property string fa_500px                               : "\uf26e"
    readonly property string fa_accessible_icon                     : "\uf368"
    readonly property string fa_accusoft                            : "\uf369"
    readonly property string fa_address_book                        : "\uf2b9"
    readonly property string fa_address_card                        : "\uf2bb"
}
```

In order to use it, I load it in my root `Item`, or in the one where I need an icon like this :

```
FontAwesome {
     id: awesome
}
```

Then use it like this :

```
Text{
    iconFont: awesome.solid
    text: awesome.icons.fa_arrow_up
}
```

Comment: I have created a script to automate the creation of icon fonts and it generates a QML component following the pattern mentioned in the answer. https://github.com/mnesarco/ff-batch

Answer (score 4):

It's apparently a lot easier today than when the previous answers were posted.

Go to the FontAwesome homepage, search for the icon you want, and download it in SVG format. Say, *bars-solid.svg* (a hamburger menu icon).

In Qt Creator, add it as say, say, *qml.qrc/images/bars-solid.svg*.

In the QML markup, add it as a property value, say, *icon.source: "images/bars-solid.svg"*

Answer (score 0):

If you want QML-only solution for loading a font:

```
FontLoader {
    source: "fontawsome.ttf"
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(name)
}
```